# Is it possible to reject non secured (non ssl / wss) websockets with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket, socket.io, cpanel

I created a Websockets server with express and socket.io, here is the code of the server:

```
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'node:http';
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

let i = 0;
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    socket.emit('chat message', ++i + ' ' + msg);
  });
});

httpServer.listen(3000, () => {
  logger.log('server running');
});
```

It works fine with both http/ws and https/wss. Now, I would like to reject any Websocket connection without ssl. In other words, if the user try to connect with ws, the connection is rejected. The following client-side code illustrate my purpose:

```
// Should be rejected
const socket = io('ws://example.com');
socket.emit('chat message', 'Hello');

// Should be processed
const socket = io('wss://example.com');
socket.emit('chat message', 'Hello');
```

My app is deployed on a production server with cPanel. I don't know exactly how ssl is managed by cPanel, but the fact is that the above code when deployed on my server works with both http/ws and https/wss requests.

Comment: Your app does not implement wss, it only implements plain websocket without TLS on port 3000. There is likely some reverse proxy in front of your app which then provides plain and TLS connectivity on the standard ports (80, 443). If you don't want to allow plain WS you need to configure there, the app has no information if if the original request came in with plain or TLS.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for the reply. If I understand well the reverse proxy manage SSL and provide plain connectivity to my node.js app ? If, for example, I force HTTP trafic to be redirected to HTTPS, my application will always receive queries that come from secured requests. Am I right?

Comment: If your reverse proxy answers any plain HTTP traffic with a redirect to HTTPS then it cannot at the same time forward plain HTTP traffic to your app. So in this case your app is not reachable by plain HTTP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thx, my app works in HTTPS without configuring any certificate in node.js. So, I guess that the server redirect HTTP to HTTPS, and then the reverse proxy redirect HTTPS to HTTP to the node.js container.